# Make abstract class method only publicly accessible from child classes

Tags: php, encapsulation, abstraction, php-7.4

First off, we're talking about PHP 7.4.10, but any general intel is appreaciated!

Summarized question: I'd like to define a static method in an abstract class in such a way, that the method can only be called publicly from child classes extending the abstract class but not from the abstract class itself. Sorry if I'm being too basic here, but I literally have been searching for hours for an answer and can't even find any discussions on the topic.

Let's consider the following example (exaplantion in the comments). I want to be able to call `Apple::printName()` and `Pear::printName()` but not `Fruit::printName()`.

```
abstract class Fruit
{
    /*
     * Oblige every child class to define a string name, nothing unusual
     */
    protected abstract static function name() : string;

    /*
     * The problem is with the access modifier of this method here
     *** 
     * If it is public, everything is fine with Apple::printName() and Pear::printName(), 
     * but one can call Fruit::printName() from outside,
     * resulting in PHP Error: Cannot call abstract method Fruit::name()
     * this is still sort of okay, since an error will be thrown anyway, 
     * but I don't want the runtime to even enter the method's body
     * I'd like to get an access restriction error.
     *** 
     * If it is protected, then we automatically can't call Apple::printName nor Pear::printName()
     ***
     * So, is there a way to define the parent static method only publicly accessible from child classes without copying code?
     */
    public static function printName()
    {
        return "My name is: " . static::name();
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit
{
    protected static function name() : string
    {
        return "apple";
    }
}

class Pear extends Fruit
{
    protected static function name() : string
    {
        return "pear";
    }
}

echo Apple::printName(); //prints "My name is: apple"
echo Pear::printName(); //prints "My name is: pear"
echo Fruit::printName(); //PHP Error: Cannot call abstract method Fruit::name() at line...
```

I'm also open for any alternative approaches as to how one might achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your instance is a subclass or not and then bail if it isnt

```php
abstract class A1 {
    public static function childrenOnly() {
        return is_subclass_of(new static, 'A1');
    }
}

class A2 extends A1 {
}
```

```php
Al::childrenOnly(); // errors out
A2::childrenOnly(); // true
```

Comment: That might be a nice little workaround, you put it once inside the parent class and done.  I ended up making both `Apple` and `Pear` abstract (since they're meant to be utility singletons) and implementing your suggestion in `Fruit`. You can see my answer for the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function printName() {}
```

This is a definition of a concrete method. One might think that it's okay to call this method since it's non abstract public method. So why `Fruit` has it if it does nothing to it ?

So one solution is to define a `trait` and `use` it only inside those that actually **need** it ?

```
trait Printer { 
    
    public static function printName()
    {
        return "My name is: " . static::name();
    }   
}

abstract class Fruit
{
    protected abstract static function name() : string;
}

class Apple extends Fruit
{
    use Printer;
    protected static function name() : string
    {
        return "apple";
    }
}

class Pear extends Fruit
{
    use Printer;
    protected static function name() : string
    {
        return "pear";
    }
}
```

If however, your `Fruit` is just a definition for child classes like you mentioned in the comment and you happen to have **PHP 8** :) then maybe just don't make `printName` static

```
public function printName()
{
    return "My name is: " . static::name();
}
```

And

```
$a = new Apple();
$p = new Pear();

echo $a->printName();
echo $p->printName();
```

Now `echo Fruit::printName();` will give you the nice Fatal error you've been looking for.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method Fruit::printName()
> cannot be called statically

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also thought of this scenario, but two main things seem just not as sophisticated and optimal to me:

- the trait `Printer` can be included in classes that do not necessarily contain a static `name()` method;

- I'll have to add `use Printer;` to every class that is **already** extending `Fruit`, which is a form of code copying in a way, although quite minimal and arguably good enough.

Thank you for the suggestion anyway, that might indeed turn out to be the best alternative, but I'm still interested if there exist other ways of achieving mentioned behavior. :)

Comment: And to answer your initial question: `Fruit` has it namely to provide it as a default functionality to all its child classes, which is needed namely because they implement the `abstract static function name() : string`, which is in turn used in the `printName()` method.

Comment: I see what you mean, although the principle includes `objects` of types and my question regards rather static implementations. I can agree that this turns out to be a violation of the Liskov principle. But let's say I want to have 100 fruit child classes, only 2 of which would need a different implementation for the static `printName()`. I would still want to provide them with a default implementation, but also the ability to overwrite it. Or is this desire in itself a violation of the Liskov principle?

Comment: I saw your update, but I'm actually more interested in the static implementations, since those are utility classes I'm trying to derive. Thank you a lot for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

So after reading all the answers I came up with a workaround-ish solution, finally deciding in favor of **@chilliNUT**'s suggestion. I ended up proceeding as follows:

```
abstract class Fruit
{
    protected abstract static function name() : string;

    /*
     * Basically, if you call the default method from any child (not necessarily a direct child) class, no problems,
     * but if you call it directly from the baseclass, you get the somewhat acceptable exception :)
     */
    public static function printName()
    {
        if(!is_subclass_of(static::class, self::class))
        {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException("Can't call base Fruit class methods directly!");
        }

        return "My name is: " . static::name();
    }
}

//those are abstract now, just to match the intention of them being utility singletons
abstract class Apple extends Fruit
{
    protected static function name() : string
    {
        return "apple";
    }
}

abstract class Pear extends Fruit
{
    protected static function name() : string
    {
        return "pear";
    }
}
```

Anyways, from @**Rain**'s answer I could see why this tends to be a bad practice and actually not the best direction to keep developing in, so I'll consider different strategies for what I'm trying to achieve. My curiosity has been satisfied at the end of the day! Thank you all for the participation!

Comment: You are welcome . Nice solution, but I thought you don't want the runtime to even enter the method's body :D

Comment: Well, you see, that's the closest to "not even entering" - it get's stopped right away after entering! :D The whole point was that I didn't want to execute unpredicted behaviour and get unpredicted errors depending on the method's body and what might or might not break inside of it.